# How to leverage Playlists for Stream video playback layout to an existing SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

I cannot find a way to get the json code for such a [playlist for Stream](https://youtu.be/Qc75U8z8mm8?t=162) video playback layout (right panel). Is it possible?

[image: Playlist-Screenshot01]

[image: Playlist-Screenshot02]

Thanks bunches!